# Google Script to copy non blank rows and append to another sheet

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Looking to copy and append all non-blank rows from a sheet tab "Form" to another sheet tab "Hold" and then delete the data from "Form".
I've tried this.:

```
// form copy  
  function formcopy(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
   var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Timestamp: ' + data[i][0]);
    Logger.log('Teacher Email: ' + data[i][1]);
    Logger.log('Teacher Requesting: ' + data[i][2]);
    Logger.log('Student: ' + data[i][3]);
    Logger.log('Purpose: ' + data[i][4]);
    Logger.log('Email: ' + data[i][5]);
    Logger.log('Date: ' + data[i][6]);
    Logger.log('Advisor: ' + data[i][7]);
    Logger.log('Time: ' + data[i][8]);
    Logger.log('Message: ' + data[i][9]);
    Logger.log('Merge Status: ' + data[i][10]);

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hold");
    sheet.appendRow([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3], 
data[i][4], data[i][5], data[i][6], data[i][7], data[i][8], data[i][9], 
data[i][10]]);
  }}   

 //Deletes Data

   function deletedata(){ 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
    sheet.activate();
    sheet.deleteRows(3,200);
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(2, 200);
    sheet.deleteRows(3);
 }
```

It does copy the data, but it copies the blank rows as well. Also, if there is a lot of data in "Form", it times out.

Comment: are there blank rows between filled rows in your dataset or are they after?

Comment: They are between.

Comment: Have you tried to add `if(data[i][0] == "") continue;` at the start of the loop? should make it ignore the rows where the 1st value is empty.

Comment: That did it! Thanks!